# Google Maps not displaying markers in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use the google maps api into an app as a school project, my problem is, the map is not displaying fully and correctly, only one part of the map is displayed, the part in Australia,
I'm unsure where the issue is as that I have followed the documentation on adding a google map to your android app.

Manifest :

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Google maps activity :

```
package com.example.mini_projet.views

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.mini_projet.R
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)


    //    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
     //   setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)


    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

        val bundle = getIntent().extras
        if (bundle != null) {
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        }
        val longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0)
        val latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0)
       // val zindex = intent.getFloatExtra("zoomindex",0.0f)
        Log.d("longitude: "+longitude,"latitude :"+latitude)
        val Restitle = intent.getStringExtra("Title")

      //  Log.d("zindeix",zindex.toString())



        mMap = googleMap
        val restaurant = LatLng(latitude,longitude)
        Log.d("rest",restaurant.toString())
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(restaurant).title("Marker in "))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(restaurant))

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
       // val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
      //  mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
       // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

I have also added my key to properties file and added the dependencies and plugins to the build.gradle

I'm unsure whatelse I can do, Thank you.

Ps: bare in mind that I'm still fairly new to android dev and kotlin.

Comment: Ok, apparently the issue is that maps takes forever to load, it's been 20 minutes now and only half the map is shown

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the emulator, I was using Pixel 5 and I'm not sure what was the issue, I just downloaded Pixel 4 and everything was solved.
There was no issue with the code itself or the key.